# how to bind .apk and .db in one .apk so user can download and run application

Tags: android, sqlite

All i need to bind .db and .apk at run time  in single .apk so user can download and run the application. i don't neeed to . db in assets ,raw ,URL path because we need to Change the .db at run time and we Have so many user and for different user we have different .db.  it is ERP based Application.  thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking, are you also saying you can't download or create a database at runtime? What do you exactly mean by bind

Comment: hi thanks for Comment actualy we need  bind to .adb to .db so after generate  we able to give the .apk to user and he Can use. for different user we need same .apk and but   different database.

Answer (score 1):

You put the .db into your /raw/ directory.

Then at runtime you copy this into a new database that is located in your applications memory, which is then modifiable.

```
  //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
  //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
  this.getReadableDatabase();

  /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }
```

The code is not mine and is an exert from the full tutorial at: [Using your own DB in Android](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

If your looking to put different database files in your /raw/ you might want to use multiple APK's now that the market allows it or make an ant script for selecting a different DB when the APK is built.